# Gettext blog posts different languages

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, gettext

I've been looking already over a month for a universal solution and hadn't come up with any.

I need to have my website international everywhere, not just UI. I also need to have my blog posts multilingual, but they are dynamic (created via CMS).

There are two problems:

1. I can use GNU Gettext for UI's localization but barely can imagine to use it for blog posts (except using some scary things, like parsing and editing .po files through PHP, then compiling it to .mo with unreliable scripts, then using some tricks to avoid Gettext cache...). So I've come up with an idea to make some database-based localization for dynamic content.
2. But it means that I need to use two different localization systems: GNU Gettext and database-based. It's ridiculous. So I need to make all localization database-based.

Am I right? Are there smarter solutions? Would appreciate a lot any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way round.

Extract the translatable strings from your database into a .pot file, for example 'database.pot'.  When you extract the messages from your php sources, do it (more or less) like this:

```
xgettext *.php database.pot
```

You can always use .po or .pot files as input to xgettext.

Then, use your regular translation workflow, and once you have to translated .po files, parse the translations out of the files, and write them back into the database.